# Detect sharp drops in time series data (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a time series DataFrame which is indexed by "Cycles" and I'd like to know if there's a way to detect ***sharp prolonged*** drops.

The data is smoothed using a rolling mean of 10k cycles. And the index is not "symmetric", meaning that each row doesn't always increase the same number of cycles.

```
Index(Cycle)    RawData    DecimatedData
     4            9.032         9.363
     6            9.721         9.359
    10            9.831         9.363
    11            8.974         9.352
    15            9.143         9.354
```

Even after decimating there are many "small" drops along the way which I'd like to ignore.

I've tried using df['DecimatedData'].diff() with different windows but it hasn't yielded good results.

I was thinking of putting a counter and that continues to increase as the .diff() function yields negative values, and then after it reaches a certain limit I can flag it. But I think there might be a more elegant way of doing this.

[image: Time series plot]

Comment: please give us more data to create/test a dataframe

Comment: The dataframe is almost 1M rows, is there a way that I can upload it here?